# Catch block not updating state in custom useFetch React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, try-catch-finally

I have made the following custom `useFetch` hook for my Next.js app:

```
import HTTPMethod from "http-method-enum";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function useFetch() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    

    const sendFetch = async (url: string, method: HTTPMethod, body: any): Promise <any> => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const rawResponse = await fetch(url, {
                method,
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    body,
                }),
            });

            const response = await rawResponse.json();
            setData(response);
        } catch (error: any) {
            setError(error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return [data, loading, error, sendFetch];
}
```

Everything is working accept for error handling. My catch block is not triggering even after a `400` error code from fetch. Instead all of the response (whether there is an error or not) is in the `data` state. When I console the error state outside the catch block I get  an empty string. I also don't get anything at all in the catch block.

When there is an error I want the response to be stored in the `error` state.

Please don't recommend Axios or any other fetch libraries as they run slow on the edge.

## Edit:

I changed my code to:

```
import HTTPMethod from "http-method-enum";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function useFetch() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    console.log(error)

    const sendFetch = async (url: string, method: HTTPMethod, body: any): Promise <any> => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const rawResponse = await fetch(url, {
                method,
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    body,
                }),
            });

            const response = await rawResponse.json();

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.message)
            }
            setData(response);
        } catch (error: any) {
            setError(error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return [data, loading, error, sendFetch];
}
```

However my state is not updating. But it will update if you a string value like so: `setError("Error")`. However when you pass in the error parameter `error` stays as an empty string.

Comment: `My catch block is not triggering even after a 400 error code from fetch.` fetch does not throw an error when it gets a 400. If you want to do that, you'll need to throw the error yourself, typically by checking `response.ok` and then throwing if it's false. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful

Comment: @Nicholas Yes but my state is not updating (see the edited section of the question).

Comment: @Phil The catch block runs the `error` state just isn't getting updated.

Comment: How are you verifying that the `error` state isn't updating? FYI you have a nasty type mismatch between the initial state (a string) and what you set it to in the catch block

Comment: @Phil To verify error is not updating I console `error` a the end on the `sendFetch` function. There is no mismatch because the response is of type `string`.

Comment: 1) Can't see that `console.log()` anywhere in your code. 2) React state setters are asynchronous so you won't see changes immediately. 3) Don't use `console.log()` for debugging. 4) `new Error()` is most definitely **not** a string